# Add alert to RSI line color change. (Tradingview Indicator - PineScript)

Tags: pine-script

Trying to add an alert condition when the RSI line changes from white to either Red or Green. I have added white arrows to indicate where alerts should be triggered. I have tried adding some in, but this is beyond my skills, and I am hopeful someone here can assist me.

```
//@version=3
study(shorttitle = "TTS", title="Complete Trend Trading System [Fhenry0331]", overlay=false)

myemalength = input(26) 
myema = ema(low, 26)

mvwaplength = input(13) 
mvwap= ema(vwap, mvwaplength)


price=close

src = close, len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

plot(rsi, color=white)

change1= rsi > 60 ? lime :na
change2= rsi < 40 ? red: na

p1 = plot(rsi, style=linebr, linewidth=4, color=change1)
p2 = plot(rsi, style=linebr, linewidth=4, color=change2)

band1 = hline(70)
band2 = hline(30)
band3 = hline(55)
band4 = hline (45)
midline = hline (50)

fill(band1, band3, color=lime, transp=90)
fill(band2, band4, color=red, transp=90)
fill(band3, band4, color=black, transp=90)

cond1 = rsi > 55 and close > myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond1 ? lime : na) 

cond2 = rsi < 45 and close < myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond2 ? red : na) 

cond3 = rsi < 50 and close < myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond3 ? yellow : na)

cond4 = rsi > 50 and close > myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond4 ? orange : na)

cond5 = rsi < 50 and close > myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond5 ? black : na)

cond6 = rsi > 50 and close < myema ? 1 : 0
barcolor(cond6 ? black : na)

cond7 = rsi > 50 and close < mvwap and close > myema ? 1 : 0
plotchar(cond7, title="Buy pullback", offset=0, char='BuyPB',location=location.top, color=lime, transp=0)

cond8 = rsi < 50 and close > mvwap and close < myema ? 1 : 0
plotchar(cond8, title="Sell pullback", offset=0, char='SellPB', location=location.top, color=red, transp=0)

cond9 = rsi > 50 and close < mvwap and close > myema ? 1 : 0
plotshape(cond9, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, color=lime, transp=0, offset=0)

cond10 = rsi < 50 and close > mvwap and close < myema ? 1 : 0
plotshape(cond10, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.bottom, color=red, transp=0, offset=0)

cond11 = rsi > 75 and close > myema ? 1 : 0
plotchar(cond11, title="take some profits", offset=0, char='TP', color=#90bff9, transp=0)

cond12 = rsi < 25 and close < myema ? 1 : 0
plotchar(cond12, title="take some profits", offset=0, char='TP', color=#b39ddb, transp=0)


//Alerts
alertcondition (cond11, title="Close Trade")
alertcondition (cond12, title="Close Trade")
alertcondition (cond1, title="Open Buy")
alertcondition (cond2, title="Open Sell")
```

RSI Picture (see the white arrows to where alerts are to trigger)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnvBT.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should Crossover/Crossunder functions, like this:

```
white_to_green = ta.crossover(rsi,60)
white_to_red   = ta.crossunder(rsi,40)

plotshape(white_to_green?60:na,location = location.absolute,style = shape.triangleup,color = change1)
plotshape(white_to_red?40:na,location = location.absolute,style = shape.triangledown,color = change2)
```

I added these lines in you above code, and this is the related result:
you see the 1-candle delay, but it's normal after the finished candle, not the live candle, furthermore, you added offset in other lines, if you remove them all shapes and colors will be synced.
[image: Indicator Result]

Comment: Thank you Arman. Can you add the entire code so I can see where you have added these lines and what has been overwritten? Thanks Ben

Comment: please give me more information about these items: 1- long entry condition 2- short entry condition 3- long exit & 4- short exit conditions